# IF no pandas retornando The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Estou com uma DS com duas colunas, uma com mês de 1 a 12, e outra com ano de 2015 a 2021, e estou tentando criar uma coluna chamada `Fiscal Year`.

Estou criando uma função para que quando o mês estiver entre 4 e 12 dentro do ano 2017 retornar FY17/18.

```
def fiscal_year(x,y):
    if ((x >= 4.0) & (x <= 12.0)) & (y == 2017.0):
        return 'FY 17/18'
    else:
        return 'nada'
```

E quando vou aplicar:

```
instal_final_csa['Fiscal Year'] = instal_final_csa.apply(fiscal_year(instal_final_csa['MÊS'],instal_final_csa['ANO']))
```

Retorna o erro:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Tente: `instal_final_csa['Fiscal Year'] = instal_final_csa.apply(fiscal_year(instal_final_csa['MÊS'],instal_final_csa['ANO']), axis=1)`. Note que acrescentei o `axis=1`

Comment: Tentei, mas retornou o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer por np.select

```
instal_final_csa2 =instal_final_csa
conditions = [((instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] >= 4 )&(instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] <= 12))&(instal_final_csa2['ANO'] == 2016),
              ((instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] >= 1 )&(instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] <= 3))&(instal_final_csa2['ANO'] == 2017),
              ((instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] >= 4 )&(instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] <= 12))&(instal_final_csa2['ANO'] == 2017),
              ((instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] >= 1 )&(instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] <= 3))&(instal_final_csa2['ANO'] == 2018),
              ((instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] >= 4 )&(instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] <= 12))&(instal_final_csa2['ANO'] == 2018),
              ((instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] >= 1 )&(instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] <= 3))&(instal_final_csa2['ANO'] == 2019),
              ((instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] >= 4 )&(instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] <= 12))&(instal_final_csa2['ANO'] == 2019),
              ((instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] >= 1 )&(instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] <= 3))&(instal_final_csa2['ANO'] == 2020),
              ((instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] >= 4 )&(instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] <= 12))&(instal_final_csa2['ANO'] == 2020),
              ((instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] >= 1 )&(instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] <= 3))&(instal_final_csa2['ANO'] == 2021),
              ((instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] >= 4 )&(instal_final_csa2['MÊS'] <= 12))&(instal_final_csa2['ANO'] == 2021),]
choices = ['FY16/17','FY16/17','FY17/18','FY17/18','FY18/19','FY18/19','FY19/20','FY19/20','FY20/21','FY20/21','FY21/22']
instal_final_csa['Fiscal Year'] = np.select(conditions,choices,default = 'nada')
```